# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked') Error in React testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I wrote code for radio button unit testing. Getting Error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked')".

[image]

Index.test.tsx

```
describe("Radio group test cases", ()=>{
    test("Radio group change value and new value updated and last value no more checked", () => {

        render(<RadioGroupWrapper touched={true} />);
    
        // Before change selection
        const radionButtonMale = screen.queryByLabelText('Male') as HTMLInputElement;
        //expect(radionButtonMale).toHaveProperty("checked", true);
        expect(radionButtonMale.checked).toEqual(true); //Here it fails
    
        // Change selection
        const radionButtonFemale = screen.queryByLabelText('Female') as HTMLInputElement;
        fireEvent.click(radionButtonFemale, { target: { checked: true }});
        expect(radionButtonFemale.checked).toEqual(true);
    
        // Old value is no more checked
        expect(radionButtonMale.checked).toEqual(false);
    });
})
```

Index.tsx

```
return (
    <>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <FormLabel id="buttons-group-label">{placeholder}</FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup
        aria-labelledby="buttons-group-label"
          value={!value ? defaultValue : value}
         // onChange={onChange}
         
          // label={placeholder}
          name="radio-buttons-group"
          {...otherprops}
        >
          {fieldConfig?.options?.map((option) => (
            <FormControlLabel key={option.displayValue} value={option.displayValue} control={<Radio />} label={option.displayValue} />
                        ))}
          
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
      {!valid && touched && <ErrorMessage>{errorMessage}</ErrorMessage>}
    </>
  );
}
```

It looks like test is executed before radio buttons render that why It is giving "property of null" error. I applied set time out but test case failed.

Comment: First of all - you should use `getByLabelText`, not the `queryByLabelText` if you are sure the element should be there, as `queryByLabelText` can return null if element is not found. So my guess - the element cannot be found. Use `screen.debug()` to see what is actually rendered.

Comment: Yes you are right if I am using getByLabelText, it shown "unable to find element", I tried getByLabelText, test-dataid but unable to get the element. It seems material ui radio crates nested dom thats why I am unable to get the element.